# Installing Microsoft Visual C++ 10/SDK 7.1 on Windows 10 (for Python packages that require VC++ 10)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++, sdk, windows-10

On trying to install the scrapy package (Python 3.4, Windows 10) I got the error message

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279
```

I have had this problem with other packages and have yet to solve it. Having read around the problem I believe there is a problem getting SDK 7.1 to install on Windows 10 because the latter comes with a pre-installed version of .NET 4 that the SDK installer does not recognise. (It says you need .NET 4, get it from ..., but the installer you get from there says .NET 4 is already installed).

My question is: does anyone know of a link to a definitive solution to either of the problems of (1) installing Python packages that claim to need VC++ 10 or (2) installing SDK 7.1 on Window 10?

Happy to provide more details on either the Python or Windows aspects of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For installation of the SDK on Windows 10, you can trick the installer into thinking you have the expected .NET version by temporarily changing the registry keys.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\Version`

and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version`

to

`4.0.30319`

Remember to set the values back after you're done!

There are various other potential solutions around as well that don't involve you modifying the registry, but this worked for me.

Comment: With right click > run as administrator as well?
Is your computer on a domain at all?

Comment: Yes, tried this as well. What role plays the domain here?

Comment: I'm not sure if being on a domain can override your permission to edit those registry settings.